# Как увеличить количество генерируемых значений в random.randint

Tags: python, генерация-случайных-данных

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы сгенерировать случайные значения в диапазоне от 300000 до 10000000.
При этом все сгенерированные значения должны попадать в список, а сумма списка не должна превышать переменную limit
Дополнительным условием еще является то, что количество значений необходимо регулировать переменной (до этого я в коде даже не дошел еще, т.к. в первой части воткнулся в проблему)
Мой код:

```
    numbers = []
    total = 0
    limit = 22494741.76
    while len(numbers) < 3000 : 
        number = random.randint(300000, 10000000) 
        numbers.append(number)
        total += number
        print(total) 
        if total >= limit:
            numbers.pop()
            numbers.append(round(limit- sum(numbers)))
            break
    print(numbers)
    print(total)
```

```
Output: 
9194174
13985772
15862135
17430413
25741680

[9194174, 4791598, 1876363, 1568278, 5064329]

25741680
```

Эта штука генерирует 4-8 значений и все... Почему генератор быстро набирает необходимую сумму? Почему количество значений так мало? Почему генератор не может сгенерировать больше значений (по количеству), но более мелкими цифрами?
Была идея сделать генератор на 1000 - 5000 случайных значений методом random.randint(min_value, max_value) все значения записать в список и потом пройтись по этому списку генератором random.choice(list_value). Но это не принесло результата... Опять получил 4-8 значений.

Comment: *"Почему генератор не может сгенерировать больше значений (по количеству), но более мелкими цифрами?"* - потому что вы сами просите числа от 300к до 10млн. Как вы думаете, если среднее ожидаемое значение `10 300 000 / 2 = 5 150 000`, то сколько таких средних поместится в ваши `22 494 741.76` - правильно, около 4.36 штук.

Comment: "_Почему генератор не может сгенерировать больше значений (по количеству), но более мелкими цифрами?_" - может. Измени диапазон получаемых чисел и будешь получать много. А если генерировать значения от 300000 до 10000000, то странно ожидать, что получаемые числа будут маленькими.

Comment: Самый простой способ, сгенерировать N значений списка т.е. столько сколько нужно, а дальше если сумма будет превышать лимит — делить все слагаемые на некоторый коэффициент (отношение результата к лимиту) подобным образом можно регулировать нижнюю границу (добавляя ее как константу к рандомному числу)

Comment: Диапазон чисел, что Вы задали, генерирует довольно большие числа, а лимит не сильно от них далёк. Соответственно сумма сгенерированных чисел достаточно быстро упрётся в лимит. Или увеличьте лимит, или измените диапазон. Допустим в диапазон 1, 100_000 помещаются 400+ значений, а 5_000_000, 10_000_000 - всего 3-4 значения. Делайте выводы.

Comment: Давайте, я немного конкретизирую задачу, что объяснит выбор констант. Дело в том, что есть тип кредита сумма которого должна лежать в диапазоне от 300000 до 10000000 руб. Лимит выдачи таких кредитов ограничен суммой 22494741.76 руб. При достижении этой суммы такой тип кредитов становится не доступен (типа акция такая). Нужно сгенерировать от 1000 строк, в которых сумма может быть любой из указанного диапазона. Вот поэтому такие константы.

Comment: Округлим Ваш лимит до 22 миллиона. Минимальное значение кредита = 300 тысяч. Сколько раз можно взять 300 тысяч из 22 миллионов? 22_000_000 / 300_000 = 73,3. То есть, максимум получится сгенерировать при идеальных условиях, когда Вы будете брать самые минимальные значения диапазона, всего 73 числа. Не выйдет тысячу раз получить числа, которые в сумме не превысят этот лимит исходя из такого диапазона. Тут не в коде проблема, а в математике

Comment: Прям как в том мультике. "А девять шапок из одной шкуры сможете сшить?" ТЗ поставлено как-то очень своеобразно. Я немного понимаю в банковских темах. Там не бывает случайных сумм, людям дают сумму не больше, чем предсказывают алгоритмы, что вот такую сумму ему дать можно, дефолта не будет. И это очень индивидуально. В общем, тут какие-то сферические кредиты в вакууме.